# Difference between initiliazing an object and super.clone()

Tags: java, data-structures, clone

I am taking data structure course and I am trying to code a DoublyLinked list and its own method.In my book I saw this code.Is there any difference between code (1) and code (2). If it does, which one should I use?

```
DoublyLinkedList<E> other=(DoublyLinkedList<E>) super.clone(); //code (1)

DoublyLinkedList<E> other=new DoublyLinkedList<>();//code (2)
```

Comment: Unless your list is empty, they do different things. (1) clones the list (2) creates a new, empty list.

Comment: One creates a clone of something (and probably in the wrong way, because normally you'd not call `super.clone()` like that, but without context hard to say), and the other creates a new and empty `DoublyLinkedList`. In other words, they do entirely different things

Comment: If it doesn't, can we say they are same things? @AndyTurner

Comment: @Leo2 I don't understand what you are asking. If what doesn't what?

Comment: In my book it just implements Cloneable and its clone method throws  CloneNotSupportedException.So should I use second code instead of one?@MarkRotteveel

Comment: In this situation,super is an Object class instance and it is casted a DoublyLinkedList. My DoublyLinkedList class just extends Object class.So do not code (1) automatically creates a new instance of DoublyLinkedList?@AndyTurner

Answer (score -1):

It depend what is write in implementation constructor of DoublyLinkedList and method "clone" of super class. You can do it differently or equally.

If you use implement "List", you must write own method clone.
"LincedList" has own method.

And read if you want this article:
Java Cloning: Copy Constructors vs. Cloning
https://dzone.com/articles/java-cloning-copy-constructor-vs-cloning

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Clonetest implements Cloneable{

    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Clonetest clA = new Clonetest();
        IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(value -> clA.ints.add(value)); //add Integers
        System.out.println(clA.ints);

        clA.ints.removeIf(integer -> integer % 2 > 0); //remove part in clA.ints

        Clonetest clB = (Clonetest) clA.clone();
        System.out.println(clB.ints);
        System.out.println(clB.ints.equals(clA.ints));
    }
}
```

Results:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
true

Comment: Here is a link for my question.luk2302's answer he used super.clone() 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419548/java-doubly-linked-list-clone-method

Comment: Yes, he used Object.clone(), it is only creation of exact copy of an object. It creates a new instance of the class of current object and initializes all its fields **with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields** of this object. It will be new object with "link to" old fields.